# How to find children of nodes using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the `<a>` tags which are children of `<li>`:

```html
<div>
<li class="test">
    <a>link1</a>
    <ul> 
       <li>  
          <a>link2</a> 
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

I know how to find element with particular class like this:

```
soup.find("li", { "class" : "test" })
```

But I don't know how to find all `<a>` which are children of `<li class=test>` but not any others.

Like I want to select:

```html
<a>link1</a>
```

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Try this

```
li = soup.find('li', {'class': 'test'})
children = li.findChildren("a" , recursive=False)
for child in children:
    print(child)
```

Comment: Or, to just extract the expression that describes what we want: `soup.find('li', {'class': 'text'}).findChildren()`.

Comment: but how to get frist <a> tag only not after wards. something like `find(li).find(a).firstChild()`

Comment: from bs4 site : "findChildren, findChild: These methods are left over from the Beautiful Soup 2 API. They’ve been deprecated since 2006, and should not be used at all: "

Answer (score 150):

There's a super small section in the DOCs that shows how to find/find_all **direct** children.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument

In your case as you want link1 which is first direct child:

```
# for only first direct child
soup.find("li", { "class" : "test" }).find("a", recursive=False)
```

If you want all direct children:

```
# for all direct children
soup.find("li", { "class" : "test" }).findAll("a", recursive=False)
```

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps you want to do

```
soup.find("li", { "class" : "test" }).find('a')
```

Comment: i think it will find `<a> link2 </a>` as well but i don't want that

Comment: This answers the question how to select `<a>link1</a>` in the HTML given in the question, but this will FAIL when the first `<li class="test">` will contain no `<a>` elements and there are other `li` elements with `test` class that contains`<a>`.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

"How to find all `a` which are children of `<li class=test>` but not any others?"

Given the HTML below (I added another `<a>` to show te difference between [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and `select_one`):

```
<div>
  <li class="test">
    <a>link1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>link2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a>link3</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

The solution is to use [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`) that is placed between two CSS selectors:

```
>>> soup.select('li.test > a')
[<a>link1</a>, <a>link3</a>]
```

In case you want to find only the first child:

```
>>> soup.select_one('li.test > a')
<a>link1</a>
```

Comment: This is the one i was looking for . I was supplying it to the wrong method. Forgot > is a CSS selector. Thanks!

Comment: How would you select only the first <a> if there were multiple in li.test?

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```
li = soup.find("li", { "class" : "test" })
children = li.find_all("a") # returns a list of all <a> children of li
```

other reminders:

The find method only gets the first occurring child element.
The find_all method gets all descendant elements and are stored in a list.

Comment: Questioner wants none of two options above. He wants all links which are only direct child.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another method - create a filter function that returns `True` for all desired tags:

```
def my_filter(tag):
    return (tag.name == 'a' and
        tag.parent.name == 'li' and
        'test' in tag.parent['class'])
```

Then just call `find_all` with the argument:

```
for a in soup(my_filter): # or soup.find_all(my_filter)
    print a
```

Answer (score 8):

Just came across this answer and checked the documentation to see that `soup.findChildren` is deprecated (BS 4.9). You can use `soup.children` instead, which only considers an element's direct children, not its descendants.

```py
li = soup.find('li', {'class': 'text'})
for child in li.children:
    print(child)
```

Documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children