# Python BeautifulSoup only select top tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I encounter a problem, it might be very easy, but I didn't saw it on document.

Here is the target html structure, very simple.

```
<h3>Top 
    <em>Mid</em>
    <span>Down</span>
</h3>
```

I want to get the "Top" text which was inside the `h3` tag, and I wrote this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="<h3>Top <em>Mid </em><span>Down</span></h3>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.select("h3")[0].text
```

But it will return `Top Mid Down`, how do I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *find* setting *text=True* and *recursive=False*:

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: html ="<h3>Top <em>Mid </em><span>Down</span></h3>"
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
   ...: print(soup.find("h3").find(text=True,recursive=False))
   ...: 
Top
```

Depending on the format, there are lots of different ways:

```
print(soup.find("h3").contents[0])
print(next(soup.find("h3").children))
print(soup.find("h3").next)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will checkout more detail about `contents` and `children`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="<h3>Top <em>Mid </em><span>Down</span></h3>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.select("h3").findChildren()[0]
```

Though I am not entirely sure. Check this as well - [How to find children of nodes using Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287529/how-to-find-children-of-nodes-using-beautiful-soup)

Basically you need to hunt the first [childNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp).

Comment: There is syntax error in your code, but thanks for your information.

Answer (score -1):

its easy for you to search using a regex
something like this

```
 pageid=re.search('<h3>(.*?)</h3>', curPage, re.DOTALL)
```

and get the each of the data inside the tag using `pageid.group(value)` method

Comment: Thanks, but I thought there would be an easier way to get the content in BeautifulSoup.