# BeautifulSoup loop isn't iterating through other nodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are quite similar scenarios regarding this; but I've been comparing with others. 
[Getting from Clustered Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287529/how-to-find-children-of-nodes-using-beautiful-soup/15892793) etc. But somehow; I'm unsure why my `for loop` isn't iterating and grabbing the text from other elements but only from the first element of the node.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/'
l = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}

response = get(url, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


def findDiv():
     try:
        for container in html_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'section-trending-search-list'}):
            topic = container.select_one(
                'div._1waRmo')
            if topic:
                print(1)
                d = {
                    'Titles': topic.text.replace("\n", "")}
                print(2)
                l.append(d)
        return d
    except:
        d = None

findDiv()
print(l)
```

[image: the html elements i'm trying to access]

Comment: shouldn't this line read:   topic = container.select_one('._1waRmo')    -in other words, just the class name.   Also the line html_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'section-trending-search-list'})   will find only the root element, don't you need to html_soup.find_all('div')  to enumerate all divs.  Or if you want to enumerate everything under div class _25qBG5, then find that (call it say toplevel, then options = toplevel.find('div')  and then for option in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/'
l = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}

response = get(url, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


def findDiv():
     try:
        for container in html_soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_25qBG5'}):
            topic = container.select_one('div._1waRmo')
            if topic:
                d = {'Titles': topic.text.replace("\n", "")}
                l.append(d)
        return d
     except:
        d = None

findDiv()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[{'Titles': 'school backpack'}, {'Titles': 'oppo case'}, {'Titles': 'baby chair'}, {'Titles': 'car holder'}, {'Titles': 'sling beg'}]
```

Again I suggest you use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). If you run this again you will see that you will get a different set of 5 dictionaries within the list. Every time you are making a request they are giving  5 random trending items. But they do have a 'change' button. If you use selenium, you might be able to just click that and keep **scraping** all trending items.

Comment: My mistake on the header, as I've forgotten to re-edit the header to include `'User-Agent': 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)`

Comment: @Minial I will delete my answer. And come up with the right solution.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I might find out more on **Selenium** because I'm sure it'll help smoothen alot of things for me in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
toplevel is finding the root of the options, then we find all divs under that.
I hope this is what you want.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/'
l = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}

response = get(url, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


def findDiv():
    try:
        toplevel = html_soup.find('._25qBG5')
        for container in toplevel.find_all('div'):
            topic = container.select_one('._1waRmo')
            if topic:
                print(1)
                d = {'Titles': topic.text.replace("\n", "")}
                print(2)
                l.append(d)
                return d
    except:
        d = None

findDiv()
print(l)
```

This enumerates fine with a local file. When I tried with the url given, the website wasn't returning the html you show.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'path_in_here\\test.html'
l = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}

example = open(url,"r")
text = example.read()

#response = get(url, headers=headers)
#html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

print (text)

def findDiv():
    #try:
        print("finding toplevel")
        toplevel = html_soup.find("div", { "class":  "_25qBG5"} )
        print ("found toplevel")
        divs = toplevel.findChildren("div", recursive=True)
        print("found divs")

        for container in divs:
            print ("loop")
            topic = container.select_one('.1waRmo')
            if topic:
                print(1)
                d = {'Titles': topic.text.replace("\n", "")}
                print(2)
                l.append(d)
                return d
    #except:
    #    d = None
    #    print ("error")

findDiv()
print(l)
```

Comment: `toplevel =  html_soup.find('._25qBG5')` returns an empty value sadly. It is what I'm looking for and I understand the concept; but somehow it's returning `None` when I do call for it.