# How to find this generic tag inside a HTML code with BS4 (beautiful soup)

Tags: python

I am trying to findo this "generic" tag (there is only a "Span" Tag). I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked out. I tried the code below but brings me more than I want (I´m trying to reach the "573 m²" only...

**Code:**

```
Meters = [headline3.get_text() for headline3 in soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "feature__container"})]
```

**Output:**

```
['\n        573 m²\n        \n        4 \n        \n        4 \n        \n        4 \n        ',
```

HTML CODE (image): [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX7Ox.jpg): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX7Ox.jpg]

Comment: Could you post sample of html as text instead of an image? And the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can find all `li` elements. Then, for each `li` element get the **first** direct `span` child element and then access it's text.

Example:

```py
meters = [li.find("span", recursive=False).get_text() for li in soup.find_all("li", { "class" : "feature__item" }) ]
```

Since there is no further way to exclude other values using HTML selectors (all are span tags), you might have to filter out values with `m²` in them manually to get your final output.

Like this:

```py
result = list(map(int, [i.replace('m²', '').strip() for i in meters if 'm²' in i]))
```

Outputs:

```
[351, 573 ...]
```

Reference:

[How to find children of nodes using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287529/how-to-find-children-of-nodes-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Hi Rithin, many thanks for helping. I tried you code above but it still returning the same:

'\n        351 m²\n        ', '\n        4 \n        ', '\n        3 \n        ', '\n        5 \n        ', '\n        573 m²\n        ', '\n        4 \n        ', '\n        4 \n        ', '\n        4 \n        ', '\n        270 m²\n        ', '\n        3 \n        ', '\n        3 \n        ', '\n        3 \n         ETc...

I was expecting: 351, 573, ... 

Thanks!

Comment: @Ferby, could you add the html input as text in the question so I can try? And your expected output?

Comment: Hi, my expected output is: [351, 573, 270, 350,...] just the numbers! It is bringing me more than the necessary . the site is: https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/aluguel/casas-de-condominio/sp+sao-paulo/?__zt=nrp%3Ab

I tried to copy but I don´t know how to copy all the lines, sorry! lol its a web scraping project.

Comment: @Ferby, please check the updated answer. You would have to manually filter text with 'm²' out and get integers back.

Comment: Rithin, thank you so much bro!! I was really stuck in this, you helped me a lot!!