# Find tag <a> and tag <img> when using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following source code:

`code`

```
<div class='aaa'>
    <div class='aaa-child'>
        <a>
           <img></img>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

`code`

So the structure is an image inside a hyperlink.

I would like to find if tags "a" and "img" exists inside the above divs. Any ideas? I tried with find_all but I get too many results that don't match my expectations.

Comment: Is this the entire document?  Did you use `find_all()` starting from the document root, or from the div shown above?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287529/how-to-find-children-of-nodes-using-beautifulsoup) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah use descendant CSS selector with a class selector:

```
soup.select('.aaa a,img')
```