# How to get a <a> tag in a nested HTML using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get  to access href links. Although my HTML is a nested structure like the image below

[image]

I'am trying to do that using BeautifulSoup4, however I'am new to WebScrapping. The code I'm using is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368301/DA+API+-+Canais+de+Atendimento"


response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    page_body = soup.find_all('div', class_= '_1bsb1osq _19pkidpf _2hwx1wug _otyridpf _18u01wug') 
    for p in page_body:
        print(p.find_all('a'))
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve content. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
```

But, my print shows an empty list `[]`

My doubt is: Is there a way to access this element directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find children of nodes using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287529/how-to-find-children-of-nodes-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired data is loaded dinamically and only Beautifulsoup can't grab data. So you can get data using  either selenium or from API request. Here I apply `selenium with beautifulsoup` and it's working fine now.

**SCRIPT:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# chrome to stay open
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368301/DA+API+-+Canais+de+Atendimento")
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

page_body = soup.select('ul.childpages-macro.conf-macro.output-block  li')
for p in page_body:
  href = p.a.get('href')
  print('https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net' + href)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/223773060
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/297533441
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/297533461
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/297533518
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/297533542
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/297533567
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368404
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368427
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368487
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368514
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368537/v1.0.1+-+Canais+de+Atendimentos   
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368560
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368587/v1.0.0-rc5.2+-+Canais+de+Atendimentos
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/17368610
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/223805833
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/223805853
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/223805910
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/223805934
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/266895490
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/266895510
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/266895567
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/266895591
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/282886145
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/282886165
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/282886222
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/282886246
https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OF/pages/283901953
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is rendered via JavaScript. To get the tree structure + links you can use this example:

```py
import json

import requests

api_url = "https://openfinancebrasil.atlassian.net/cgraphql?q=NonRecursivePageTreeQuery"

payload = [
    {
        "operationName": "NonRecursivePageTreeQuery",
        "query": 'query NonRecursivePageTreeQuery($spaceKey: String!, $statuses: [GraphQLPageStatus], $ptStatuses: [PTGraphQLPageStatus], $contentId: ID!, $paginationLimit: Int, $isSuperAdmin: Boolean!) {\n  currentPage: page(\n    id: $contentId\n    spaceKey: $spaceKey\n    pageTree: $paginationLimit\n    status: $ptStatuses\n    enablePaging: true\n  ) {\n    ...PageInfoFragment\n    nearestAncestors {\n      pageInfo {\n        hasNextPage\n        endCursor\n        __typename\n      }\n      nodes {\n        ...PageInfoFragment\n        previousSiblings {\n          ...PageListFragment\n          __typename\n        }\n        followingSiblings {\n          ...PageListFragment\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    previousSiblings {\n      ...PageListFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    followingSiblings {\n      ...PageListFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    children {\n      ...PageListFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  rootLevelPages: pages(spaceKey: $spaceKey, status: $statuses) {\n    nodes {\n      ...PageInfoFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  space(key: $spaceKey) {\n    id\n    homepage {\n      id\n      __typename\n    }\n    operations {\n      operation\n      targetType\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment PageInfoFragment on Page {\n  id\n  title\n  status\n  hasChildren\n  blank\n  hasRestrictions @include(if: $isSuperAdmin)\n  hasInheritedRestrictions @include(if: $isSuperAdmin)\n  type\n  links {\n    webui\n    __typename\n  }\n  properties(keys: ["emoji-title-published", "emoji-title-draft", "editor"]) {\n    nodes {\n      id\n      key\n      value\n      version {\n        number\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PageListFragment on PaginatedPageList {\n  nodes {\n    ...PageInfoFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  pageInfo {\n    hasNextPage\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n',
        "variables": {
            "contentId": "17368301",
            "isSuperAdmin": False,
            "paginationLimit": 500,
            "ptStatuses": ["CURRENT", "DRAFT"],
            "spaceKey": "OF",
            "statuses": ["CURRENT", "DRAFT"],
        },
    }
]


def find_pages(o, level=0):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        new_level = level
        if o.get("type") == "page":
            yield o, level
            new_level += 1

        for v in o.values():
            yield from find_pages(v, new_level)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from find_pages(v, level)


data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for page, level in find_pages(data):
    print("\t" * level, page["title"], " -- ", page["links"]["webui"], sep="")
```

Prints:

```
Open Finance Brasil -- /spaces/OF/overview
[DA] API - Canais de Atendimento -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368301
        [DA] API - Produtos e Serviços -- /spaces/OF/pages/17367858
        Tabela verdade para envio de informações relativo a Serviços e Tarifas -- /spaces/OF/pages/225247233
        [DA] API - Títulos de Capitalização -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368637
        [DA] API - Investimentos -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368743
        [DA] API - Câmbio -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368866
        [DA] API - Credenciamento -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368974
        [DA] API - Previdência -- /spaces/OF/pages/17369082
        [DA] API - Seguros -- /spaces/OF/pages/17369190
        [DA] API - Contas -- /spaces/OF/pages/180257084
        [DA] API - Cartão de Crédito -- /spaces/OF/pages/180257194
        [DA] API - Direitos Creditórios Descontados​ -- /spaces/OF/pages/180061315
        [DA] API - Empréstimos -- /spaces/OF/pages/180256974
        [DA] API - Financiamentos -- /spaces/OF/pages/180257414
        [DA] API - Adiantamento a Depositantes -- /spaces/OF/pages/180257304
        Dados Abertos - DA -- /spaces/OF/pages/17367790/Dados+Abertos+-+DA
                Dados do Cliente – DC -- /spaces/OF/pages/17369300
                Serviços - SV -- /spaces/OF/pages/17375877
                Relatórios e Métricas -- /spaces/OF/pages/17376817
                Padrões -- /spaces/OF/pages/17377278
                Problemas Conhecidos das Especificações -- /spaces/OF/pages/17377541
                Política de Versionamento -- /spaces/OF/pages/86835214
                Webhook -- /spaces/OF/pages/105021457/Webhook
        Especificações de APIs -- /spaces/OF/pages/17367659
                Comunicados & Eventos Técnicos -- /spaces/OF/pages/17367092
                Especificações de Integração -- /spaces/OF/pages/17377794
                Segurança -- /spaces/OF/pages/240648193
                Diretrizes Técnicas e Operacionais -- /spaces/OF/pages/17378512
                Certificação de Conformidade -- /spaces/OF/pages/17378880
                Requisitos não Funcionais -- /spaces/OF/pages/17956981
                Problemas -- /spaces/OF/pages/17379123/Problemas
                Suporte -- /spaces/OF/pages/17379146/Suporte
                Histórico de Alterações -- /spaces/OF/pages/17379274
        Open Finance Brasil -- /spaces/OF/overview
        Campos regulatórios - [DA] Canais de Atendimento -- /spaces/OF/pages/223773060
        v2.0.0 - [DA] Canais de Atendimento -- /spaces/OF/pages/297533441
        v1.0.2 - [DA] Canais de Atendimento -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368404
        Histórico de Especificações - [DA] Canais de Atendimento -- /spaces/OF/pages/17368514
```